# How can I declare a memory address as argument of a function?

Tags: c

Let's suppose I have two addresses mapped in memory:

```
#define MY_REGISTER_1 (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x1B))
#define MY_REGISTER_2 (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x18))
```

I wanna create a function that set a bit in one register, like this:

```
set_bit_low(MY_REGISTER_1, 3);
```

Is it correct to declare my function as below?

```
void set_bit_low(uint8_t, uint8_t);
```

Comment: Does your toolchain support the `register` keyword? If so, can you use this: `void set_bit_low(register uint8_t, register uint8_t);`? This is a hint to make the compiler use a hardware register if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your definitions:

```
#define MY_REGISTER_1 (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x1B))
```

dereferences the octet at address `0x1b`, so it represents the *content* of your memory mapped register, rather than its location. It would be preferable to have a macro with the location of your register(s):

```
#define REGISTER_1 ((volatile uint8_t *) (0x1B)) /* Substitute _1 for some meaningful name */
```

which you can then dereference at will, and you can declare your function as follows:

```
void set_bit_low(volatile uint8_t *register, uint8_t bitpos);

/* Use like this: */
set_bit_low(REGISTER_1, 3);
```

Comment: I can't change my definition, but you shows me the real point. So, instead of `set_bit_low(REGISTER_1, 3);` I use `set_bit_low(&REGISTER_1, 3);`

Comment: If you cannot change the macro definitions, you should use the idiom described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18983038/149530).

Comment: I've put a comment there explaining why I'm trying to do in this way.

Comment: Fair enough, but bear in mind that way is much more readable and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be the correct way to declare your function:

```
void set_bit_low(uint8_t *, uint8_t);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You want to alter the content of the memory location. So, you must pass it as pointer.

The function header should like

```
void set_bit_low(uint8_t *, uint8_t);
```

The function shoul like

```
void set_bit_low(uint8_t *my_reg, uint8_t bit_location)
{
   // do your bit manupulation here by assigning to *my_reg.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
#define MY_REGISTER_1 (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x1B))
```

Yields *a copy* of the value in the (mem mapped) register.  So this:

```
set_bit_low(MY_REGISTER_1, 3);
```

Would pass that copy to `set_bit_low()`.  You can then set the bits *in the copy* (which would be local to the function).  If you want to set bits of the value *in the register*, then you have to pass the address itself:

```
#define MY_REGISTER_1_ADDR 0x1b
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Many answers already mentioned that passing `MY_REGISTER_1` the way you defined it to a function would result in a copy of it to be sent. However, the actual solution often used in microcontrollers is different than what the other answers suggest.

Usually, the registers *are* defined the way you defined them, i.e.

```
#define MY_REGISTER_1 (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x1B))
#define MY_REGISTER_2 (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x18))
```

is ok. However, you should take care not to pass them to a function if you expect them to be changed by that function. The cleanest way to perform bit manipulation of such registers is through macros. For example:

```
#define SET_BIT_LOW(reg, n) (reg) &= (uint8_t)~(1 << (n))
#define SET_BIT_HIGH(reg, n) (reg) |= (uint8_t)(1 << (n))
```

This not only correctly manipulates the actual register, but also has the added benefit that you avoid a function call. If these were functions, `n` wouldn't be known and therefore the shift and not operations would have to be done either way as well as a (relatively) costly function call. With macros, the compiler could already calculate the right-hand-side expressions if `n` is a constant and replace the line with 1 or 2 instructions.

Comment: Normally I use in this way, too. But I think it could be a problem because you are repeating the argument `reg`. So I think it could be substituted by an inline function.

Comment: @DanielGrillo, am I repeating the argument `reg`?

Comment: `(reg) |= (uint8_t)(1 << (n))` is the same of `(reg) = reg | (uint8_t)(1 << (n))`. I said `you` but in generally. Sorry my English.

Comment: Maybe I'm nitpicking, I don't know.

Comment: @DanielGrillo, `x |= y` is "semantically" the same as `x = x | y`, but they are not treated by the compiler exactly like that. If `x` has a side effect (which here it doesn't), it would still be done once in `x |= y`. Still, even if you put it in an inline function, you wouldn't be avoiding a read on the register followed by a write. That's the minimum you have to do to change a bit and these macros do that minimum.

Comment: That's not necessarily true -- microcontrollers tend to have set-bit and clear-bit instructions which do not require a separate read. And in that case, you definitely want to use a|=b instead of a=a|b, as that's the construct the compiler is most likely to emit the setbit instruction for.

Comment: @ben, that's completely true. That's yet another reason why I would recommend macros instead of functions (noting that not all microcontroller compilers support inline functions).